# Caching a graph with guava

Tags: caching, guava

I am working on an routing algorithm for which i have to compute a graph first. With the current version of my program getting a route takes more than 8s basically because i create the graph with each route request.
That is why i am looking for a way that could speed up the process of finding the route. After doing some research i understood that i can calculate the graph one time then load it in memory and accessing it from there. All sounds cool and easy but when i try to put it in practice i get stuck.

I chose google's guava as a caching method, i did hear that its pretty easy, but for the life of me i do not understand how can i make this work for an entire graph, my knowledge is very limited in this area. I can do it for one string but no idea on how i can do it for a Graph object.

I found in documentation something defined like this but really i see no way to set this up.

```
    LoadingCache<String, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
           .maximumSize(1000000)
           .build(
               new CacheLoader<String, Graph>() {
                 public Graph load(String key) {
                   return createExpensiveGraph(key);
                 }
               });


   private static Graph createExpensiveGraph(String key){
          LineStringGraphGenerator graphGen = new  LineStringGraphGenerator();
          for (ListIterator l = lines.listIterator(); l.hasNext(); ){
            LineString line_graph = (LineString) l.next();
            graphGen.add(line_graph);
          } 
          networkGraph = graphGen.getGraph();

          return networkGraph;
   }
```

Comment: So what's missing? The code to create the graph?

Comment: No, i do have the code, but would that be all?

Comment: What part doesn't work?

Comment: Hmmm i do not understand the part on how would i get the graph from cache to further process it? Also i have added the graph creation function to the main post.

Comment: In your case: `graphs.get(key)`.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't modify your graph when you compute the route, or it's not going to be reusable: cached data should be _immutable_ (at least effectively).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But how would i assign a key to the graph so that it should be identified based on it? I guess that's what it does not make sense for me. Because i create the graph during the createExpensiveGraph method when setting up the cache. I guess i should use the graph.put(key, graph) method . But there is no graph. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @user3253067 Did you figure it out? Just in case: the key represents all the parameters needed to create the graph. If it doesn't depend on anything for its creation (where does it come from, though?), you don't really need a `Cache` but more probably an `AtomicReference` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I was able to figure it out however because my knowledge is limited in this area i do have a question to which you might know the answer. Is it possible to access the object cached from another java project?

Comment: @user3253067 If by "another Java project" you mean another application running separately (be it in a separate JVM or simply in a separate classloader), then no: the Guava cache is not distributed and does not have a remote API. For that you need to turn to other solutions, such as [EHCache and/or Terracotta](http://ehcache.org/), [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org/), [JCS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/), [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/), etc. (not in any particular order).

Comment: Oook, thanks a lot. I was avoiding EHCache because i find it a bit complicated, but looks like i have to go back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be resolved from google, post like:
[this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/09/building-lightweight-in-memory-caches-with-google-guava-no-more-putifabsent/) or [this other](http://java.dzone.com/articles/caching-guava) are an introduction of Guava Cache.

The basic example is:

```java
public class YourCacheClass {

    private final LoadingCache<String, Graph> graphs;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 1000000;

    YourCacheClass() {
        super();
        this.graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(MAX_SIZE)
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<String, Graph>() {
                        public Graph load(String key) {
                            return createExpensiveGraph(key);
                        }
                    });
    }

    /** Method to get graph */
    public Graph getGraph(String key) throws ExecutionException {
        return this.graphs.get(key);
    }

    private Graph createExpensiveGraph(String key) {
        //your code to load Graph
        return graph;
    }

}
```